# Universal central extension of Lie algebras

Tags: reference-request, ra.rings-and-algebras, lie-algebras, lie-algebra-cohomology

In the literature, there is the notion of the universal central extension of a Lie algebra. My question is: is there also a notion of universal extensions that are not central? If yes, can you provide a reference please and if not, why is there none?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $K$ be the ground field. An extension of a Lie $K$-algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ means a pair $(\mathfrak{h},p)$ where $p$ is a surjective homomorphism $\mathfrak{h}\to\mathfrak{g}$. A homomorphism between extensions $(\mathfrak{h}_1,p_1)$, $(\mathfrak{h}_2,p_2)$ is a $K$-algebra homomorphism $f:\mathfrak{h}_1\to\mathfrak{h}_2$ such that $p_2\circ f=p_1$. A universal extension of $\mathfrak{g}$, is naturally defined as an initial object in this category.

In the full subcategory of central extensions, an initial object is called a universal central extension (and unlike the claim in a comment to this answer, is a well-adapted definition). This is classical, as well as the fact that a universal central extension of $\mathfrak{g}$ exists if and only if $\mathfrak{g}$ is perfect.

In the whole category of extensions of $\mathfrak{g}$, one has:

> Then there is no universal extension of $\mathfrak{g}$ except for $\mathfrak{g}=\{0\}$.

This holds in the category of Lie $K$-algebras, or also, if $\mathfrak{g}$ is finite-dimensional, in the category of finite-dimensional Lie $K$-algebras.

Since $\{0\}$ is an initial object in the category of Lie algebras, $\{0\}\to\{0\}$ is a universal extension. Hence suppose $\mathfrak{g}\neq\{0\}$. By contradiction, let $(\mathfrak{h},p)$ be a universal extension, so $\mathfrak{h}\neq\{0\}$. Consider the first projection $q:\mathfrak{g}\times\mathfrak{h}\to\mathfrak{g}$. Then both homomorphisms $(p,0)$ and $(p,\mathrm{id})$ from $\mathfrak{h}$ to $\mathfrak{g}\times\mathfrak{h}$ lift $p$, and this contradicts the uniqueness in the universal property.

(Note: this is a variation of the argument to show that if $\mathfrak{g}$ is not perfect then it has no universal central extension.)

---

Edit:

> Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a full subcategory of the category of abelian extensions of $\mathfrak{g}$, not consisting of central extensions. Then there is a no universal $\mathcal{C}$-extension (i.e., no initial object in $\mathcal{C}$).
>
> In particular, for $\mathfrak{g}\neq\{0\}$, there is no universal abelian extension of $\mathfrak{g}$.

Proof: let $(\mathfrak{h},p)$ be a universal extension in $\mathcal{C}$. Let $(\mathfrak{s},q)$ be non-central extension in $\mathcal{C}$, with kernel $Z$. Let $f:\mathfrak{h}\to\mathfrak{s}$ be given by the universal property. Choose $z\in Z$ not central; then $\tau:s\mapsto s+[s,z]$ is an automorphism of $\mathfrak{s}$, inducing the identity of $\mathfrak{s}$ modulo $s$. By the uniqueness in the universal property, it follows that $s\circ f=f$. Hence $f$ is valued in the set of points fixed by $s$, which is the centralizer of $z$. Since $q\circ f$ is surjective, we also have $f(\mathfrak{h})+Z=\mathfrak{s}$. Combining, we deduce that $z$ is central, contradiction.

(The second assertion follows since every nontrivial $\mathfrak{g}$ has a nontrivial $\mathfrak{g}$-module, hence has a non-central abelian extension.)

Comment: I think your definition of "universality" is not quite adapted to extensions of groups or Lie algebras. Already in the case of central extensions, by "universal" we usually only mean that the factorisation of morphism should exist, but it is almost never unique, essentially because the extension can have non-trivial automorphisms if we define the notion of morphisms between extensions naively. We can require stronger condition such as the factorisation should be unique after "fixing its restriction on the kernel".

Comment: @WilleLiou I don't think so. In the central case, with the same definition I chose, there is no automorphism. Indeed, let $\mathfrak{h}$ be a perfect Lie algebra, with a quotient $\mathfrak{g}$ with central kernel $Z$. Let $f$ be an endomorphism of $\mathfrak{h}$ inducing the identity on $\mathfrak{g}$. Write $f(x)=x+s(x)$ with $s$ linear map $\mathfrak{h}\to Z$. Writing $f([x,y])=[f(x),f(y)]$ yields $[x,y]+s([x,y])=[x,y]$, so $s$ vanishes on commutators and hence is zero, thus $f$ is the identity.

Comment: I'm not so sure about your calculation. Just take the the case of strictly upper triangular $3\times 3$ matrices (Heisenberg): it is a central extension of $\mathbf{C}\times \mathbf{C}$ by $\mathbf{C}$. There are non-trivial inner automorphisms, which of course lifts the trivial automorphism on $\mathbf{C}\times \mathbf{C}$ because the latter is abelian.

Comment: @WilleLiou it is not a perfect group/Lie algebra, so has no universal central extension. I explicitly assumed perfect in my previous argument. It's not "my" definition, but a widely used definition, see for instance Weibel's book. A group or Lie algebra has a universal central extension iff it's perfect.

Comment: Okay, I give a "perfect example" for groups. Consider $G = \mathrm{PGL}_2(\mathbf{C})$ and $H = \mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbf{C})$. We can define an automorphism $\sigma:H\to H$ as follows: For any $g\in H$, we can factorise $g = \det(g)^{1/2}g_0$ with $g_0\in  \mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{C})$ and $\det(g)^{1/2}$ is the scalar matrix of one of the square roots of $\det(g)$. Define $\sigma(g) = (\det(g)^{1/2})^{-1}g_0$, which clearly does not depend on the choice of square root. It is a homomorphism because scalar matrices are central. Then $\sigma$ lifts the identity map on $H$ but is non-trivial.

Comment: @WilleLiou $GL_2(C)$ is not perfect...

Comment: @YCor Thank you for your answer and sorry for the late reply. Just one question: why do you restrict the Edit to abelian extensions? A priori, it seems to me that your proof should also work for non-abelian Lie algebra extensions, yes? Where does it break down?

Comment: @Sleipnir basically to avoid a more technical statement. In general, I'd need to assume the existence in $\mathcal{C}$ of a non-essentially-central extension. Here, essentially central means that the centralizer of the kernel surjects onto $\mathfrak{g}$. For an abelian extension, essentially central means central (since the centralizer of the kernel contains the kernel). A trivial (direct product by something arbitrary) extension is essentially central.

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion, it's probably not so interesting to consider all extensions. 
If you consider the Lie subalgebra $\mathfrak{n}_n\subset \mathfrak{gl}_n$ of all strictly upper triangular matrices, then $\mathfrak{n}_n$ is an extension of $\mathbf{C}$ because it has a quotient Lie algebra of dimension 1. It follows that even for nilpotent extensions the nilpotency can grow arbitrarily large.
Of course extensions can be even more chaotic than that.

**Edit**
Example of a non-central perfect group extension: Consider block matrices over $\mathrm{C}$
$$
 H = \begin{pmatrix}\mathrm{SL_2} & * \\ 0 & \mathrm{SL_2}\end{pmatrix},\;
 K = \begin{pmatrix}I_2 & * \\ 0 & I_2\end{pmatrix},\; G = H/K \cong \mathrm{SL}_2\times \mathrm{SL}_2
$$
The group $H$ is perfect because its Lie algebra is perfect: The diagonal part $\mathfrak{sl}_2\times \mathfrak{sl}_2$ lies in the commutator because $\mathfrak{sl}_2$ is perfect. On the other hand, we have
$$
X = \begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 & b & a \\ 0 & 0 & d & c \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}, Y = \begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\end{pmatrix},\; [X, Y] = \begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 & a & b \\ 0 & 0 & c & d \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}
$$
so the off-diagonal part is also in the commutator.

Consider the conjugation by the matrix $\mathrm{diag}(1, 1, -1, -1)$. It acts non-trivially on $H$ but trivially on $G$.
It means that non-central extensions can in general have non-trivial automorphisms even if the extension is a perfect group.

Comment: I think this was the idea (to allow arbitrary kernels). In particular this allows the surjective homomorphism from the free Lie algebra over $\mathfrak{g}$ onto $\mathfrak{g}$. Why should it be uninteresting? anyway I doubt there's a universal extension in general.

Comment: @YCor Usually a universal extension is some kind of projective limit. Already in the case $\mathbf{C}$, we see that there is a infinite sequence of extensions, so the projective limit of the sequence will be a topological Lie algebra with the limit topology. I tend to think that even if some kind of universal extension existed, there should be a topology on it so Lie algebras without topology are not enough.

Comment: I would suggest you to get acquainted with the literature existing on the subject, such as Weibel's book and others.

Comment: (Regarding your edit) indeed this is typical in non-central extensions with abelian kernel; there is also a similar example in the extension $\mathrm{SL}_2(K)\ltimes K^2\to\mathrm{SL}_2(K)$. Possibly with some more effort one can reach the conclusion that there is no universal (abelian kernel extension) of any nonzero Lie algebra.

Comment: ِYou are right about central extensions. I was confusing central extensions of Lie algebras with extensions in abelian categories.

Comment: This example also implies that the universal extension doesn't exist because we can compose the map from the universal extension to $H$ by any inner automorphism. It changes the map because the image contains a conjugate of $G$ inside $H$ and $G$ is not central in $H$.

Comment: Right, composing with an inner automorphism (with respect to some element in the kernel) produces failure of the universal property. Using this I added in my answer the non-existence in general of a universal abelian extension.

Comment: I find it immature to downvote the other answer, anyway I won't counterbalance by downvote.

Comment: @YCor If you mean me, I didn't downvote anyone...